# VB/ASP Sending SMS to multiple number in database using For Each

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

Hey guys can someone give me an idea for this:

for example i have a database filled with the numbers of the contacts i want to send my sms with. how can i use **for each** to read all the numbers and send the sms to them. like this one ? ***i dont know the correct syntax yet***

**Example:**
database: tblnumbers

```
for each(number in the tblnumbers)
{
    execute my sms code to send to the numbers.
}
```

thats my logic only.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the below could give you a *very* broad idea of what is required here... There simply isn't enough information to give you an accurate answer. This question should probably be closed for being too broad...

Please note, the below code uses my own helper classes. It's for demonstration only.

I suggest you research how to interact with databases using .NET and how to populate and manage collections such as lists, dictionaries and arrays.

```vb
private sub SendSms()
    Const query as string = "SELECT * FROM [TBLNUMBERS]"
    using dr as new DataReader(_globals.Dif)
        dr.ExecuteReader(query)
        do While dr.read()
            dim telNo as integer = dr.Item("TELEPHONE_NO")
            'Do something with the telephone number...
        Loop
    End Using
End sub
```

Comment: what does the .DIF means ?

Comment: As I stated, this solution is for demonstration only and uses my own helper classes which you are not privy to